# Can I enter Dubai airport visa-free if I have a valid H-1B visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dubai, us-residents, flydubai

I am flying to the USA on an H-1B from India. I believe I am eligible for a visa on arrival in Dubai Airport, since I have a valid US visa. I am planning to stay in Dubai for 2 days. Should I apply for a transit visa?

Does the airline help apply for the transit visa? I just wanted to make sure whether I need to have a visa before flying. Anyone with past experience?

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of [Emirates web site sharing of the Timatic tool](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=AE&DV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=5d9a5df925d0cb84fa52a2c3c20609127281eb6), the information used by airlines for passenger entry requirements (and as noted in the deleted @HankyPanky response), you would not require a visa (bold italic added emphasis mine):

> **Destination - United Arab Emirates (AE)**
>
> **Passport**
>   Passport required.
>
> **Document Validity**:
>   Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
>   Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to passengers who stay less than 3 months must be valid for a minimum of 3 months from the arrival date. This does not apply when entering in Abu Dhabi (AUH).
>   **Admission and Transit Restrictions:**
>   Admission refused to passengers with a hand-written passport at Dubai (DXB).
>   **Additional Information:**
>   Passengers with dual nationality must present the same passport at immigration upon entry and departure.
>   **Warning:**
>   Visitors with an extended validity in their passports are not allowed to enter.
>   **Visa**
>   Visa required.
>
> **Visa Issuance:**
>   E-visas can be obtained before departure at www.ednrd.ae . Passengers must have a printed e-visa confirmation. Airlines can check the validity of the e-visa on the same site by clicking on "Query GDRFA-D APP".
>
> ***Nationals of India with a normal passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date with a visa issued by USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State which is valid for a minimum of 6 months can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days. They can apply to extend their stay for an additional 14 days.***
>
> Passengers with a normal passport and a confirmation that a visa has been approved before departure can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 96 hours, 30 days or 90 days. Passengers must have a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date. The visa approved before departure must be deposited by the sponsor at the Immigration Authorities.
>
> - Deportation on the same flight will follow if sponsor (or representative) is not present at the time of passenger's arrival at the airport.
>
> **Additional Information:**
>   Valid visas in expired passports are accepted provided accompanied by new passport.
>
> **Warning:**
>   Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

Comment: TL;DR in other words, you need a visa but there's a visa on arrival option.